# Excel Equi-Depth Binning (Dynamically analyze data to bin values)

Tags: excel

I am just wondering whether anybody can help me in regards to understanding and implementing equi-depth binning dynamically in excel.

I managed to achieve equi-width binning using excels data analysis histogram feature. But given that equi-depth requires bins to have an equal amount of values within them, I am slightly confused as to how to get this working dynamically.

Obviously I can manually do this, but that seems very redundant.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with the Percentile.Inc function?So if you wanted 3 equi-depth bins, you would use Percentile.Inc(data_Array, .33), Percentile.Inc(data_Array, .67), Max(data_Array) as the upper bounds of your bins

Answer (score 0):

First, designate a cell to contain the number of bins you want. Let's use $X$1. Suppose it has a 4 in it. In cell X2, put the header "bin #".

Now, in cell X3, place this formula:

=IF(ROW()-2>$X$1,"",ROW()-2)

And fill it down (say, 30 rows, in case you want more bins later). For now, there should be 4 values, 1-4 and the remaining cells come up blank. Now in the cell to the left (W3), place this formula:

=IF(X3="","",IF(X3=1,0,PERCENTILE.INC(Table1[Data],X2/$X$1)))

$W$3:$X$30 now define the bins and you can do a VLOOKUP (with range-lookup = TRUE)